# Can any smooth even function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be written as a smooth function of $x^2$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth ($C^\infty$) even function, then the Taylor expansion at any point contains only even powers of $x$. Is it true that $f$ can be written as a smooth function of $x^2$? Similarly, if $f$ is an odd function, the Taylor expansion around any point has a factor of $x$ that can be factored out. In this case, can $f$ always be written as $x\cdot g(x)$ for some smooth $g$?

Comment: it seems to me that yes, because you can factor out the $x^p$ from the series and then identify the serie to a $C^{\infty}$ function

Comment: Write $g(x) = f(\sqrt{x})$ in the first case, and $g(x)=f(x)/x$, with $g(0)=0$, in the second case, and try to prove that $g$ is smooth.

Comment: @MarineGalantin But $f$ is not real analytic.

Comment: @Jeff I suppose you mean $f(\sqrt{|x|})$. But $\sqrt{|x|}$ is not differentiable at $0$, I don't see a reason why composition with $f$ is not only differentiable but even smooth.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, sorry for deleting my comment, I thought I did it fast enough.

Comment: Yes, I mean $\sqrt{|x|}$. To extend to negative $x$, you could define $g(x) = \text{sign}(x)f(\sqrt{|x|})$. The nondifferentiability can be killed by the evenness of $f$. For instance if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f(\sqrt{|x|}) = |x|$ and $g(x)=x$, which is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is a theorem by Whitney, have a look to [this page](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077471799#ui-tabs-1).

Comment: According to the theorem "$g(u)$ is determined for $u\geq 0$ but not for $u<0$".

Comment: @freakish The statement of the theorem is the one written as "Theorem 1", not what is written as an introduction to the paper.

Comment: If you are not convinced, have a look to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72497/if-f-is-smooth-and-even-then-there-exists-a-smooth-function-g-such-that-fx